# "function does not exist," but I really think it does

Tags: postgresql

Am I crazy or just plain dumb?

```
dev=# \df abuse_resolve 
List of functions
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Schema              | public
Name                | abuse_resolve
Result data type    | record
Argument data types | INOUT __abuse_id bigint, OUT __msg character varying
Type                | normal

dev=# select abuse_resolve('30'::bigint); 
ERROR:  function abuse_resolve(bigint) does not exist
LINE 1: select abuse_resolve('30'::bigint);
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Here's the `CREATE FUNCTION`, I've omitted the meat of the code, but that should be irrelevant:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION abuse_resolve(INOUT __abuse_id bigint, OUT __msg character varying) RETURNS record AS $_$
DECLARE
    __abuse_status    VARCHAR;
BEGIN
 ...snip...
    UPDATE abuse SET abuse_status    = __abuse_status,
                       edate    = now(),
                       closed_on = now()
                 WHERE abuse_id        = __abuse_id;
    __msg = 'SUCCESS';
END;
$_$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;
```

And just for giggles:

```
GRANT ALL ON FUNCTION abuse_resolve(INOUT __abuse_id, OUT __msg character varying) TO PUBLIC;
GRANT ALL ON FUNCTION abuse_resolve(INOUT __abuse_id, OUT __msg character varying) TO myuser;
```

That function seems like it exists. What could I be missing?

This is resolved, the answer is: I'm dumb. I had improperly defined the arguments originally, but my code was using the correct ones. There was an extra `bigint` that had no business being there.

Comment: Can you post the `create function` statement?

Comment: Did you execute both in the same session? Same user? Same search_path?

Comment: Yes, there's only one user. search_path is set to public, SHOW confirms this. I'll edit with CREATE FUNCTION

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, something is odd. I did:

```
steve@steve@[local] =# create function abuse_resolve(inout __abuse_id bigint,
                               out __msg text) returns record language plpgsql as
                               $$ begin __msg = 'ok'; end; $$;
CREATE FUNCTION
steve@steve@[local] =# \df abuse_resolve
List of functions
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------+----------------------------------------
Schema              | so9679418
Name                | abuse_resolve
Result data type    | record
Argument data types | INOUT __abuse_id bigint, OUT __msg text
Type                | normal

steve@steve@[local] =# select abuse_resolve('30'::bigint);
-[ RECORD 1 ]-+--------
abuse_resolve | (30,ok)
```

Have you had any other issues with this database? Can you copy it with dump/restore and try this on the new copy? Does explicitly qualifying the function name with the "public" schema help? Which version of PostgreSQL are you using?

*update: sql function*
It also worked fine for me using:

```
create function abuse_resolve(inout __abuse_id bigint, out __msg text)
  language sql as $$ select $1, 'ok'::text $$;
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce @echtish creating the function as sql without `returns record`. Then I saw your sample as plpgsql and dropped my own and created yours and it worked. Then dropped yours and I now can't reproduce the problem anymore with the same function with which I was reproducing the problem at first. I'm using 9.1 on Fedora 16

Comment: The only sensible explanation is that the `search_path` does not include the `public` schema. I bet that `select public.abuse_resolve('30'::bigint);` works.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: I can't reproduce it using a SQL function either (9.1, Debian)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: but in that case, I would not expect the function to be findable with `\df`, which applies `pg_function_is_visible`.

Comment: You are right, it makes no sense. `\df` would not show the function then.

Comment: Version is 9.1.2. I've tried dumping with -c and re-importing with the same result. I have similar functions defined that perform similar tasks (abuse_deny) that work without problem. They use the same parameters, were defined the same way. I think there's something silly I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 4):

If you can and if is that problem. I recommend to use

```
"set search_path = mainSchemaName, secondOnes"
```

to set correct schema where function is created or in a place where you call it directly specify the schema name

```
select schemaName.abuse_resolve('30'::bigint);
```

Comment: This is it. right here. I forgot to define my schema name before my function and that was causing it to not work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM abuse_resolve('30'::bigint);
```

Comment: Thanks, but no joy. Still, `ERROR:  function abuse_resolve(bigint) does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

I had everything but no usage on the schema. Granting usage on schema fixed it.